# Get Poweshell script to run in Exchange Power Shell on opening

Tags: powershell, exchange-2013

I have a script for extracting mailbox sizes from our exchange server saved in a .ps1 file.

```
Get-MailboxDatabase | Get-MailboxStatistics | Select DisplayName, ItemCount, TotalItemSize(MB) | Export-CSV "mailboxsize3.csv"
```

When I right click it there is a menu option to "Run with Powershell"

What do I need to add to the script or to the exchange server so that I can get it run in Exchange Management Shell.

Kind regards

Matt

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your profile to load the Exchange stuff as you normally would for PSRemoting using Exchange ...

[Connect to Exchange servers using remote PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-server/connect-to-exchange-servers-using-remote-powershell?view=exchange-ps)

... or you need to install the EMS on your workstation, and add the Exchange snapin via your profile

[Install the Exchange management tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/plan-and-deploy/post-installation-tasks/install-management-tools?view=exchserver-2019)

[How to add Exchange Snapin to Powershell?](http://tech-trainer.info/how-to-add-exchange-snapin-to-powershell/)